# Поиск элементов, находящихся до минимального в массиве

Tags: c++

Нужно составить программу:

> Найти все элементы одномерного массива М(15), что находятся раньше его минимального элемента, записать в массив М1, а другие в М2

Comment: [Правила размещения учебных заданий](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/05/blog-post_21.html)

Comment: @toris, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, работа за автора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i<25; i++){
   if (m[i]<x){
       m1[] = m[i];
   }
   else{
       m2[] = m[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: а можно пожалуйста полностью листинг программы

Comment: @KARTOH. Не меньше, а РАНЬШЕ!

Comment: Если x это индекс минимального элемента, то правильно. Но из данного куска кода что такое x не понятно, потому что нет кода нахождения минимального элемента. Еще m1[]=m[i] и m2[]=[i] это запись куда?

Comment: ПРошу, напишите полный листинг программы

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int m[15],m1[15],m2[15];
    int i,imin,min;
    // заполнение массива м случайными числами от 0 до 99:
    for(i=0;i<15;i++) { m[i]=rand()%100; printf("%d ",m[i]); }
    printf("\n");
    // Поиск минимального элемента:
    imin=0; // здесь будет индекс минимального элемента
    min=m[0]; // здесь будет значение минимального элемента
    for(i=1;i<15;i++) if(m[i]<min) { imin=i; min=m[i]; }
    // Копирование всех элементов до минимального в массив m1:
    for(i=0;i<imin;i++) { m1[i]=m[i]; printf("%d ",m1[i]); }
    printf("\n");
    // Копирование всех остальных элементов в массив m2:
    for(i=imin;i<15;i++) { m2[i-imin]=m[i]; printf("%d ",m2[i-imin]); }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  const int L = 15;
  int M[L], M1[L], M2[L];
  int Min = 99, Imin;
  randomize();
  for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
  {
    M[i] = random(100);
    if(M[i] < Min)
    {
      Min = M[i];
      Imin = i;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < L; i++)
    if(i < Imin]
      M1[j++] = M[i];
    else
      M2[k++] = M[i];
  return 0; 
}
```